# Kubuntu stays on black screen after installing on iMac A1311

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, mac

I've been trying to get Kubuntu working on my iMac A1311 (2011ish I think?), but everytime i try to boot after the installer is done it just gives me a black screen. Also, I could only get the installer to work after selecting the safe graphics option on the GRUB menu.
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and all of this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!